# Executar um método em um elemento HTML sem utilizar o evento click

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, typescript

Boa noite, tenho um radio button em um formulario, onde ele só é chamado quando atende a condição de um *ngIf, porém, quando o ngIf é aceito e esse elemento é chamado, preciso que um método seja executado, sem que seja necessário clicar em botão algum.
Segue meus trechos de código:

```
<mat-radio-button name="G01" *ngIf="getClass0()" class="margem" value=0 checked>0</mat-radio-button>

    Desabilitar(element){
var radio = document.getElementById(element) as HTMLInputElement;
if(radio.style.display == 'none'){
  radio.style.display = 'table-cell';
}else radio.style.display = 'none';
```

}

Preciso que esse método seja chamado, assim que esse rádio button apareça na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Você não deve utilizar window.onload, pois alguns elementos podem ser carregados assincronamente e então nesses casos podem ainda não ser encontrados.

Para ter uma maior garantia utilize:

Se está acostumado com jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  Desabilitar(...)
});
```

Se quer algo sem dependência, utilize:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   Desabilitar(...)
}, false);
```

Saiba que é quase certo que os exemplos acima funcionarão, mas ainda sim podem não funcionar em alguns browsers, então esse exemplo abaixo é garantido em qualquer browser:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  Desabilitar(...)
}, 3000);
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Na verdade, eu não quero executar a função assim que a página é carregada, mas sim quando o radio button é carregado. Ele não é carregado assim que a página é aberta, ele possui um *ngIf, e só é carregado quando a condição do mesmo é satisfeita

Comment: desculpe, não tinha lido direito .. não sei como te ajudar, mas uma maneira não muito trivial seria encapsular o componente em uma diretiva, e esse diretiva checar com setTimeout(fnc, time) se o componente já existe e executar o que deseja ...